# Why am I getting fake virus alert pop-ups on Facebook?

Tags: windows, malware, web-browser

This happens quite often. When I am browsing through safe websites suddenly a scary virus alert comes with a toll free number to call and it hijacks the browser. Sometimes I have to end the browser process from task manager to close the browser and get rid of that pop-up. I have not installed any malicious software on my computer.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this pop-up please? thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are infected with malware. I would recommend a complete system reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably malvertisement, i.e. malware or scareware (like in your case) delivered inside the sites advertisement. Or you have some malicious ad-injecting browser extension installed or some ad-injection software like Superfish. Hard to tell what exactly is the case.

In the first case it might get fixed by installing an ad-blocking software, at least unless the site in question currently tries to work around ad-blocking software. In the other cases check your system for browser extension or some strange software. Note that browser extension turned malicious in the past and that ad-injecting software often comes bundled with some free software.

Comment: @beginner it would be nice if you wrote what it was, so another who stumbles on this question in future can benefit.